# Integrating sum of multiple trig functions under a square root

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Trying to find the length of a Lissajous knot using
$$
\int_a^b \sqrt{(x')^2 + (y')^2 + (z')^2} dt,
$$
where $x, y$ and $z$ are the parametric equations for a 3D curve.

Using certain equations I've wound up with the integral
$$
\frac1{\sqrt2}
\int_0^{2\pi}
 \sqrt{74-9\cos(6t+0.2)-16\cos(8t+1.4)-49\cos(14t)} dt,
$$
from which I have no idea how to proceed. I can find the value of the definite integral easy enough with a calculator but I'd like to be able to turn it into an indefinite integral and find the antiderivative.

Any input would be much appreciated. Is there any other method of finding the length of a curve I was not aware of?

Comment: [A numerical approximation is 36.76, put the expression here and check the “Integrate Numerically Only” checkbox in Options.](https://www.integral-calculator.com/)

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac1%7B%5Csqrt2%7D+%5Cint_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi%7D++%5Csqrt%7B74-9%5Ccos%286t%2B1%2F5%29-16%5Ccos%288t%2B7%2F5%29-49%5Ccos%2814t%29%7D+dt) agrees